# Removing somewhat duplicate records in table using MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table that compares the competitiveness of airline routes in United States. So, some of the fields in the table are id, route_id1, route_id2, airline_id1, airline_id2, sources_airport_id, and destination_airport_id.
This table is the result of self joining the routes table which consists of route maps.
But as the result, the table has somewhat duplicate records.

For example,
route 1 is competitive with route2 because they have the same source_airport and destination_airport but different airline_id. But I have two records comparing route1 to route2 and route2 to route1. They are the same comparison, but just ordered differently.

I've tried to fetch the duplicates by self-joining:
SELECT t1.*
FROM routes AS t1, routes AS t2
WHERE t1.route_id1 = t2.route_id2 AND t1.route_id2 = t2.route_id1
But this query just gets the same number of records in the table.

How do I get rid of the "duplicate" data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have no condition to separate `t1` and `t2`. First you'll get duplicates where `t1` and `t2` are swapped. Secondly, if any rows have `route_id1 = route_id2`, you'll get those rows too, in both `t1` and `t2` of the result set.

The simplest way to get around this would be:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM routes AS t1, routes AS t2 
WHERE t1.route_id1 = t2.route_id2 AND t1.route_id2 = t2.route_id1
      AND t2.id > t1.id
```

The added criterion is that one row must have a larger id than the other. This means that `t1`, as returned, will always be the row with the lower id. You can of course replace it with a < or swap the parameters to get the row with the upper id.

That will get rid of most of the duplicates. If you have proper duplicates too in the database, those will create some duplicate rows in the result set of the above query. The reason is that a "duplicate" might be detected as being a "duplicate" of two different corresponding rows, which in turn are actual duplicates of each other.

Answer (score 0):

in the select use the actual names of the fields and use the DISTINCT clause instead of using t1.* .
in the list of field make sure you do not include the airline_id as those are different and they would make your records not duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "`SELECT DISTINCT t1.* FROM ...`"?